# Finding the second specific link text element on a page and clicking it through python

Tags: python

The code that I am trying to select is:

```
 <a rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/users/1721915/unfollow">(x)</a>
```

Since I am not sure how to target a rel or data-method, I opted to target the link text '(x)', the issue is that there are two (x) elements on the page and I need to select the second one on the page. Any ideas how to reprogram this?

```
 click_friend = browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text('(x)')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `find_elements_by_partial_link_text` (note the `s` in `find_elements`) to find all the tags containing `(x)` and then get the second one:

```py
click_friend = browser.find_elements_by_partial_link_text('(x)')[1]
```

Alternatively, if you prefer to find by `data-method` you can use a CSS selector:

```py
click_friend = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('a[data-method="delete"]')
```